# UITextField not setting NSString

Tags: nsstring, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have a pickerView in a popOver.
When the user selects a row from the pickerView, it should be stored into a UITextField (`subject`)

The method i'm having troubles is:

```
- (void) viewWithPickerController:(ViewWithPickerController*) viewWithPickerController didSelectValue:(NSString*) value
{   NSLog(@"selected value is: %@",value);
    subject.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",value];
    NSLog(@"subject is: %@",subject.text);

}
```

Where value is the row of the pickerView: it logs the right value but it doesn't set it to the textField `subject`, which seems to be null.

Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your "`subject`" IBOutlet is set.

If you're doing this picker view method before your XIB / view controller is instantiated, that would explain why `subject` is a nil object.

How else would you be instantiating "`subject`"?

Comment: Yeah, i just noticed that i forgot to set the connection! Damn me! Thank you.

Comment: Don't feel bad. Most iOS devs might not admit it, but everyone makes simple mistakes like this pretty often.

Comment: Yes, definitely! When you think you're sure you've connected everything.. here it comes the error! :)